# Cross-platform filesystem watcher, running in VM watching host?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, filesystems, mac

Can anybody suggest a way to copy data from a VM's host to the VM[0] in way that is cross-platform across hosts (i.e. Windows, Mac or Linux)? Right now, I'm achieving this by running rsync in the VM in a loop, which is obviously not great.

On a high-level, I'm providing a consistent build/testing environment for developers using wildly inconsistent dev environments. When a developer clones the codebase, a VM is launched in the background to run rolling incremental builds and tests as they edit code on the host machine.

My current implementation has the VM mount a synced folder containing the source code as read-only. I don't want the VM to write anything to the host filesystem, as it might interfere with manual builds or tests the developers run. So, I have the VM copy the contents of the source directory to a guest only filesystem[1].

I'm performing this copy by running an everlasting bash script to rsync the contents every three seconds.

```
while true
do
    sleep 3
    rsync -av --exclude '.git' --exclude-from $MOUNTDIR/.gitignore $MOUNTDIR/ $BUILDDIR/
done
```

Obviously, this isn't ideal.

I've looked into using various filesystem watchers (based on inotify or kqueue), but they are all tied to a specific type of filesystem (NTFS, ext3/4, HFS+).

Is there any cross-platform way of watching for filesystem changes? Either some abstraction over filesystem specific push notification services, or a platform agnostic polling system?

Does such a thing exist in any existing library or tool? Or is there some common pattern that I'm missing here.

[0] Virtualbox hypervisor, provisioned by Vagrant, running Ubuntu, but I'm flexible on all those dependencies.

[1] I tried doing this by symlinking to the mounted folder, but our build system, `gulp`, would resolve symlinks causing pain

Comment: I've reworded this to be more general, not specifically asking for a tool. Can you re-open the question @Sven?

Comment: Also, is there any good forum for asking for the existence of tools to do something? Serious question. I have a very good idea of exactly what it is I want, and I just want to find out if it exists before I try and write it myself.